# Aggregation-framework: optimization

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document structure like this

```
{
    id, 
    companyid,
    fieldA1, 
    valueA1, 
    fieldA2, 
    valueA2,
    .....

    fieldB15, 
    valueB15,

   fieldF150
   valueF150    
}
```

my job is to multiply fieldA1*valueA1 , fieldA2*valueA2   and sum it up  to new field A_sum = sum( a fields * a values),  B_sum = sum(b fields * b value), C_sum ,  etc 
then in the next step I have to generate final_sum =  ( A_sum*A_val + B_Sum*B_val .....)

I have modeled to use aggregation framework with 3 projections for the three steps of calculations - now on this point I get about 100 sec for 750.000 docs, I have index only on _id which is a GUID. CPU is at 15%

I tried to group in order to force parallel ops  and load more of cpu but seems is staking longer.
What else can I do to make it faster, means for me to  load more cpu,  use more paralelism?

I dont need for match as I have to process all docs.

Comment: I honestly doubt that you can speed this up, as you basically have to scan though all docs.

Comment: Doing the math, that would mean that each scan could only take 133 microseconds - including seek times, reading and putting the document through the pipeline. SSDs have a "seek time" of somewhere 50-100 microseconds. Which would leave 33-83 microseconds to read and process the data.

Comment: And you can't use indexed queries, as [the docs state](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes): "Even when the pipeline uses an index, aggregation still requires access to the actual documents; i.e. indexes cannot fully cover an aggregation pipeline."

Answer (score 0):

You might get it done using [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/), as the scanning of the documents would be done in parallel.

Simply measure the time your aggregation needs now, and calculate the number of shards you need using

```
((t/100)+1)*s
```

where t is the time the aggregation took in seconds and s is the number of existing shards (1 if you have a standalone or replica set), rounded up, of course. The 1 is added to be sure that the overhead of doing an aggregation in a sharded environment is leveraged by the additional shard.

Answer (score 0):

my only solution is to split the collection  into smaller collections (same space after all) and command computation  per smaller collections (via c# console line) using parallel library  so I can raise CPU to 70%. 
That reduces the time from  aprox 395s, 15%CPU (script via robomongo, all docs) to 25-28s, 65-70%cpu (c# console app with parallelism)

using grouping  did not help in my case. 
sharding is not an option now.